# Issue getting simple promise to work when code is in different file

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I am trying to do:

1. Call a function in file B from file A and return result as promise in file A.

This is the code I have:

index.html

```
<script>
$("#link").click(function() {
    firstFunction();
});


post.done(function(r) {
  console.log(r);
});
</script>
<button id="link">Hello</button>
```

**code.js**

```
function firstFunction() {
console.log ("hello");
var post = $.ajax({
  url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: { 
  },
});
};
```

I get this error which I only seem to get if I put the main function in a different file:

```
indexboll.html:23 Uncaught ReferenceError: post is not defined
    at indexboll.html:23
```

Comment: because post's scope is to the block scope of the function.....

Comment: @epascarello I'm not really sure what that means - are you saying they have to be in the same file?

Comment: You declared `post` with `var` inside that function; it has nothing to do with whether it's in the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the variable post is not in scope any more. Read [this](https://css-tricks.com/javascript-scope-closures/) for more info. Once `firstFunction` executes then the reference for the local variables inside it is gone. you can return the value of post out of the function by adding `return post` to the body of `firstFunction` then changing the click handler to look like this:

```
$("#link").click(function() {
   var post = firstFunction();

   post.done(function(r) {
      console.log(r);
   });
});
```